# Does Assembly.Load(Byte[]) leave a trace on the disk?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, system.reflection

We have a program that downloads the required component from the cloud.

```
var buffer = TcpClient.DownloadDll().ToBytes();
var assembly = Assembly.Load(buffer);
```

Because this is a very important core component, and it is written in C#, it is easily hackable. We only hope that it exists in memory.

We want to know if the Assembly.Load(Byte[]) method will leave traces on the disk in any way?
Is it possible for the contents of this assembly to be cached on disk by the system?

Comment: Like any memory usage, a copy of the data may be written to the paging file.  Beyond the low odds on modern machines with multi-gigabyte of RAM and the considerable effort of digging it out of that file, nothing that a door with a lock can't fix.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you very much for your answer! Besides the memory aspect, we mainly want to know how the Assembly.Load(Byte[]) method works and whether it might cache byte array to disk? For example in the GAC?

Comment: Asked and answered.  The ultimate flaw in the reasoning is that you assume an attacker will do this the hard way when the simple way is to intercept or spy on the TCP traffic.  Which doesn't even require physical access to the machine.  Do not make decisions like this yourself, you don't know enough to make the right ones.  Hire a security consultant.

Comment: Bear in mind also that a hacker could attach a debugger and pull your DLL straight out of memory anyway

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for your reminder, I realize that I have made a mistake. But security issues aside, I do want to know how the "Load(Byte[])" method works, and I've been working on it all day, reviewing a lot of information, but I'm still not sure if it might caches byte array to disk, so I want to understand this from a technical point of view to solve my confusion today. In any case, thank you!

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, thank you. But I do want to know how the "Load(Byte[])" method works.

Comment: This is what we're asking you: why do you care? I don't think it caches it on disk, but security-wise it shouldn't make a difference. You shouldn't have the visibility of code itself as a security issue: there is no code in the world which is impervious to this kind of assault, and the only way around it is to make the way the code works secure.